# Is it acceptable to say that a divergent series that tends to infinity is 'equal to' infinity?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, sequences-and-series, limits, notation

Consider a divergent series that tends to infinity such as $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots$. The limit of this series is unbounded, and I have often seen people say that the sum 'equals infinity' as a shorthand for this. However, is it acceptable to write $1+\frac{1}{2}+\frac{1}{3}+\frac{1}{4}+\cdots = \infty$ in formal mathematics, or is it better to denote that the limit is equal to infinity? If so, how does one do this?

Comment: its fine, there is no problem as far that you mean by this infinite the infinite defined in the extended real line

Comment: Infinity in limiting analysis is really just a notation. So yes, you can.

Comment: In formal mathematics you would just say the sum diverges. You would not say that it equals infinity. You might want to say that the partial sums are unbounded - that's one way a sum can diverge; there are others.

Comment: Although it is sloppy, we can say "the sum diverges to $\infty$". But "the sum equals $\infty$" is not valid, $\infty$ is not a number, not even with the definition of the extended line. If we consider $\infty$ to be a number , we land inevitably in trouble.

Comment: To everyone that tells you "this is just a notation" ask them what isn't a notation. Yes, it is as valid as writing $1+1=2$. It is actually better than saying "diverges", since it actually gives more information. Not all divergent series diverge by tending to infinity.

Comment: It's perfectly valid if working in the extended reals. $+\infty$ is a legitimate value in that case as long as we adhere to the restriction that $\infty - \infty$ is undefined and $0 \times \infty$ may or may not be defined depending on context. Here there's no issue as we're summing a series of nonnegative values. Lebesgue integration and measure theory would actually be more cumbersome if we didn't admit $\infty$ as an allowable value.

Comment: I'm starting to believe that some people do have an interest in students being confused. This question was clearly asked by someone who is working on the basics for now. Milo Brandt's answer below and Bungo's comment above are clearly off topic.

Comment: One unambiguous thing to say is that the series $1 + \frac{1}{2} + \frac{1}{3} + \frac{1}{4} + \cdots$ *"diverges to $+\infty$"*. This has the advantage of reminding one of *convergence to (a finite value)* while simultaneously reminding one that the series does not, in fact, converge ---  instead, it diverges. I've seen this terminology in some textbooks, for example [Fitzpatrick's "Advanced Calculus"](https://bookstore.ams.org/amstext-5) (which I quite like).

Answer (score 34, accepted):

Yes - it is both very common and entirely correct to do so. There is a bit of formal trickery here because $\infty$ is not a number, but you can do analysis with it anyways - meaning limits and that sort of thing. In particular, there is a set called [*the affinely extended reals*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Special:Search/affinely-extended_real_line) which is basically the real numbers $\mathbb R$ along with two new objects $\infty$ and $-\infty$, one at each 'end'. This is a *topological space*, meaning that you can take limits in it, but be careful that some things like $∞-∞$, $0·∞$, $0/0$ and $∞/∞$ are undefined.

Consider that, for real numbers $x$, the definition of a sequence $s_n$ converging to $x$ is as follows:

> For any $\varepsilon >0$, there exists some $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $|s_n-x|<\varepsilon$.

This can be rewritten as saying:

> For any open interval $I$ containing $x$, there exists some $N$ such that for all $n > N$ we have $s_n\in I$.

The idea behind either of these definition is that if we choose some "neighborhood" of $x$ - consisting of $x$ and at least some positive radius around $x$ - the sequence eventually is constrained in that neighborhood. More formally, a *neighborhood* of a real number is any set $S$ containing an open interval around $x$. Then, you can define convergence to $x$ as follows:

> For any neighborhood $I$ of $x$, there exists some $N$ such that for all $n >N $ we have $s_n\in I$.

To define limits to $\infty$ and $-\infty$, one just needs to define their neighborhoods. In particular, $\infty$ is meant to be the "upper end" of the real line - and being close to $\infty$ means that a number is very large. So one defines a neighborhood of $\infty$ to be any set $I$ containing an interval of the form $(C,\infty]$ for some $C\in\mathbb R$. Then, we say

> $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty} s_n = \infty$ if for every neighborhood $I$ of $\infty$, there exists some $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $s_n\in I$.

This is equivalent to saying that $s_n$ converges to $\infty$ if, for every $C$, there exists an $N$ such that if $n>N$ then $s_n > C$ - which is the usual definition you find in textbooks (but note that it is actually a theorem - a consequence of the definition of $\infty$!) - and that in *any* context that you might allow a statement like $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n = \infty$, you might as well be working in the extended reals.

Then, since infinite sums are just limits of partial sums, it is perfectly rigorous to write
$$\sum_{n\rightarrow\infty}\frac{1}n = \infty$$
and to know that this truly means that the left hand side evaluates to $\infty$, not to think that this is some special statement where equality is not equality. This is actually very common in real analysis (the branch of mathematics dealing with limits, continuity, differentiability, and all that stuff) - especially in subfields like measure theory and sometimes in the theory of metric spaces as well.

However, it is also important to know that many people do not share the view that $\infty$ is always a perfectly valid object, defined by its neighborhoods. So, even though you would technically be *right* to write such an equality, it might not go over well with your audience nonetheless - and you should keep your audience in mind whenever you write anything because "formal correctness" is no substitute for "understood by your audience" - and you will often encounter examples of things which are *technically* correct, but might confuse or annoy your audience nonetheless.

(Sidenote: The limit $n\rightarrow\infty$ in the subscript $\lim_{n\rightarrow\infty}s_n$, as you might notice, is *also* defined by the neighborhoods: we get to restrict $s_n$ by forcing $n$ to lie in some neighborhood of $\infty$ that *we* get to choose - which is what's going on when we say that there's some $N$ so that if $n>N$, blah blah blah)

Comment: Although everything in your answer is obviously correct, I wanted to avoid this point of view because it's going to induce more confusion among weak students than it's going to help those who understand well already. But that's just me adapting my speech to my audience :-)

Comment: Hello! I clarified the "extended reals", added a link to the wikipedia article, and added a tiny warning to be careful with the affinely extended reals. I hope you don't mind. =)

Comment: I just realized, that this is a simple example for a space where not every convergent sequence is a cauchy sequence.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier It depends on what is being taught. In calculus, yeah, extended reals are only marginally helpful and likely to be very confusing. Beyond introductory analysis, they start to fit easily into the theory that's already being taught and introducing them unifies a lot of edge cases involving $\infty$ into conceptual theorems - and the alternative is having lots of edge cases whose proofs are *almost* identical to the general case (except for switching out neighborhoods!), which imposes a real mental load on students, and lets errors creep in through these edge cases.

Comment: @lalala That's not really the case - in every metric space, all convergent sequences are Cauchy. The trouble is that the usual metric on $\mathbb R$ doesn't extend to the extended reals (...even if you allow infinite distances, since then you get the wrong topology) - so you can't speak of Cauchy sequences at all in it. (Of course, the extended reals are metrizable since you can map them bi-continuously to $[-\pi,\pi]$ by $\tan^{-1}$, but then you're introducing arbitrary choice in the metric and also, then it's true that all convergent sequences are Cauchy)

Comment: @MiloBrandt For sure, yet there is nothing in the way the question is being asked, that could make you think that the OP is anywhere beyond elementary matter.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Now go [clean up your mess](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3459844/does-i-infty).

Comment: I didn't understand this answer when I first read it, but now with a little more knowledge about calculus, it makes a lot of sense to me. Thanks.

Comment: I have two questions though: (1) why does the fact that the extended reals is a topological space mean that you can take limits in it; and (2) why are neighbourhoods defined as open intervals (as opposed to closed intervals); for example, what problems would there be if we rewrote the epsilon-delta definition of a limit as the following: we say that $\lim_{x \to a}f(x)=L$ iff $$\forall \epsilon > 0 \exists \delta > 0 \text{ such that } 0<|x-a|<\delta \implies |f(x)-L|\leq\epsilon \, ?$$

Comment: Since I used a less than or equal to sign, it seems we are talking about $f(x)$ being within a closed interval of $L$ as opposed to an open interval. Does this make any difference? Or am I misunderstanding what you are saying?

Comment: @Joe (1) A topological space is (at least under one of many equivalent definitions) just a set $X$ + the information of which subsets of $X$ are neighborhoods of which values $x$ - and a limit is defined in terms of both that set $X$ and the idea of a neighborhood. Then $\lim_{i\rightarrow\infty}a_n = L$ means that for every neighborhood $U$ of $L$ there is some $N$ such that if $n\geq N$ then $a_n \in U$. So, what I mean is precisely that saying that the extended reals is a topological space is simply saying "we have all the data we need to define limits" - i.e. we know about neighborhoods.

Comment: @Joe (2) Note that I defined a neighborhood of $x$ to be a set *containing* an open interval around $x$ - so $[-1,1]$ is a neighborhood of $0$ (though, be warned, some authors use "neighborhood" to mean "open neighborhood" which is a set that is open - i.e. is a neighborhood of every point it contains - which is not true of closed intervals). Your statement works out to be equivalent because "contains an open interval containing $x$" is equivalent to "contains $[x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon]$ for some $\varepsilon >0$" - although the latter is certainly a less common way to say the same thing.

Comment: @MiloBrandt Okay, I think I understand now. So the neighbourhood itself doesn't have to be an open interval—it simply has to be a set containing an open interval. And the advantage of open neighbourhoods is that, for example, $(3,5)$ is not just a neighbourhood of $4$—it is a neighbourhood of every $x\in(3,5)$. Furthermore, the closed interval $[x-\varepsilon,x+\varepsilon]$ is a neighbourhood of $x$, since it contains an open interval containing $x$. And your definition of limits is 'for every neighbourhood...', meaning that our definitions of limits are equivalent. Do I understand correctly?

Comment: @MiloBrandt And thank you for taking the time to revisit this question.

Comment: @Joe Yes, that's exactly it.

Answer (score 10):

The only thing that you can correctly write is that a limit is equal to infinity.

Be aware that writing this is nothing but a shortcut for the longer sentence $\forall M\in \Bbb R,\exists n\in \Bbb N, $ etc. It **doesn't mean** that there is a limit which is a number and that this number is $\infty$.

Comment: This is the best answer in my opinion. As long as we are talking about the standard integers and the standard reals, the sum doesn't exist in this case, so the equation is just a shorthand for a more formal limit expression.

Answer (score 10):

- Let $\{s_n\}$ be a sequence of real numbers with the following property:

  > For every real $M$ there is an integer $N$ such that $n\geq N$ implies $s_n\geq M$.

  We then write
  $\displaystyle
  \lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\infty.
  $
  This expression has a clear definition as above. We sometimes write $+\infty$ instead of $\infty$.
- In your example, by the definition above, one writes
  $\displaystyle
  \sum_{k=1}^\infty\frac{1}{k}:=\lim_{n\to\infty}\sum_{k=1}^n\frac{1}{k}=\infty.
  $
- In real analysis, one very often works with the [extended real numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line), especially in the theory of measure and integration. One can interpret the symbol $\infty$ as an extended real number and the expression $\displaystyle\lim_{n\to\infty}s_n=\infty$ can be understood as convergence in $\mathbb{R}\cup\{\infty,-\infty\}$ with the [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_real_number_line#Order_and_topological_properties). One may also work with the extended non-negative real axis $[0,+\infty]$ with the extended topology. See for instance, [this set](https://terrytao.wordpress.com/2010/09/19/245a-notes-2-the-lebesgue-integral/) of notes.
- Moreover, observe that a function $n \mapsto x_n$ from the [extended natural numbers](https://ncatlab.org/nlab/show/extended+natural+number) ${\Bbb N} \cup \{\infty\}$ (with the [order topology](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Order_topology)) into a topological space $X$ is continuous if and only if $x_n \to x_{\infty}$ as $n \to \infty$, so one can interpret convergence of sequences as a special case of continuity.

---

> "The limit of this series is unbounded"

Notes: "[bounded/unbounded](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bounded_set)" is a concept for some *subset* of real numbers. One can say "some sequence of real numbers is unbounded", or "certain *subset* of real numbers is unbounded". It does not make sense to say that the *limit* of [the partial sums of] a series is "unbounded". In your particular case, one could say that the limit of [the partial sums of] the series "is not a real number" or "is not *finite*".

Answer (score 6):

It is widely accepted for divergent series that tends to infinity the following short notation

$$\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n =\infty$$

instead of the extended version usually introduced at first by the formal and rigorous definition

$$\lim_{N\to \infty }\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n =\infty,\quad\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n \to \infty \iff \forall M\in \mathbb R \quad\exists N_0\in \mathbb N \quad\forall N\ge N_0 \quad \sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n>M$$

Comment: I really don't like the first, even if it *is* used, first because the OP specifically asked about formal mathematics, and second because it is not good practice. Students write plenty of incorrect mathematics with no need for us to help them.

Comment: @ArnaudMortier I specify better that is is just a "short notation".

Comment: Note to anyone: $=\infty$ is not normally used as a notation for divergent series. The series $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$ diverges in the Cauchy sense, but $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n=\infty$ isn't used to denote this.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I mean "divergent to $\infty$" of course since we are dealing with the harmonic series. BTW I would say that $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$ is "not convergent" and not that it diverges.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I've added "that tends to infinity", as stated in the OP, to be more clear with that. Thanks

Comment: If there is a series that deserves to be called divergent is $\sum_{n=1}^{\infty}(-1)^n$. Divergent = *dis* (apart) + *vergere* (to bend, turn, tend toward) = go in different directions.

Comment: @conditionalMethod I'm not claiming that this way is widely adopted. I use convergent when $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n =L\in\mathbb R$, divergent when $\sum_{n=1}^\infty \frac1n =\infty$ (or $-\infty$) and not convergent otherwise.

Comment: your first notation is as rigorous as the others. There is no more "rigourosity" by using limit notation or $\epsilon-N$ notation

Comment: @Masacroso What I mean is that we at first introduce the concept by $\lim_{N\to \infty }\sum_{n=1}^N \frac1n$ and then introduce the short notation. I agree with you that once there is an agreement on the meaning on is equivalent to the other.

Comment: @Masacroso Discussion about notation are always interesting. I've modified a little bit. I hope now it can be considered almost fine.

Answer (score 6):

A plea from a high-school teacher:  Do not use $=\infty$ anywhere in any school course.  The idea of infinity already causes a great deal of confusion amongst schoolchildren (as well as fascination), and our best approach is to say firmly that, 'Infinity is not a number, but an idea, and the notation $\infty$ is used as shorthand in a few standard pieces of notation.'

Yes, I know that everything in mathematics is an idea, and that every mark on the page is notation, but leave that to university philosophy classes.  What we don't want is monstrosities such as $\infty - \infty = 0$ and $\infty / \infty = 1$, which school-children routinely arrive at if we give even a hint that infinity is a number.

(I wouldn't be using $=\infty$ in undergraduate courses either.  Without a rigorous axiomatic understanding of mathematics, plus some projective geometry, it is misunderstood and misused.)

Comment: Thank you. Man, I was starting to feel a bit alone here.

Comment: @Sid Thanks, I think this is the most appropriate answer considering the level at which I am working at. Can you clarify the following statements to ensure I am not getting confused: a) there are different number systems, including the _real numbers_, and the _extended reals_, b) calculus tends to use the former, whereas analysis the later, c) No matter which number system you are using, series are defined to equal the limit of the partial sums, d) Since infinity is not treated like a number in calculus, you cannot say the limit "equals infinity" (rather, there is no limit)

Comment: @Sid e) In analysis, where the concept of infinity is rigorously defined, it is acceptable to say the sum "equals infinity" because the limit can be said to be infinity (as infinity can in this particular case be treated as a number)